# Flask js files not loading due to template folder and static folder file structure

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

So I'm trying to make a website where I'm able to just drag and drop folders containing HTML, js, and CSS files into a "library" directory and have those files served on my flask app. There's one big problem I haven't been able to get over. The problem is that all of these HTML files link to their respective js files using relative paths. For example:

```
<script src="js/keyboard_input_manager.js"></script>
```

and these files are 2 folders deep into my (combined) templates/static folder. I could fix this by doing

```
<script src="library/2048/js/keyboard_input_manager.js"></script>
```

but that is very tedious, especially when working with so many files.

TLDR: If I were to run my flask app and load a template, it wouldn't load any js or CSS because of relative paths.

**Is there any way to go about this without individually changing each path to relate to the templates folder?**

Example of my current filesystem:

```
-FLASK PROJECT
   |->library (templates/static folder)
   |    |->2048
   |       |->index.html, index.css, index.js
   |    |->Game2
   |       |->index.html, index.css, index.js
   |->main.py
```

What I've Tried:

- Using Blueprint but I can't create a whole blueprint for every file?
- Messing with paths of template folder and static folder

Flask Noob - Please let me know if I'm leaving out any helpful information :) Thanks

Comment: Two things here:
1) Does adding the <base> tag path in your html solve the problem?
2) If not, one option I see is setting an id attribute in the script tags of the js files and writing a javascript to mod the path of only the js files.